# Replace using jquery even on html tags

Tags: jquery

Sounds simple, but I spent at least 6 hours with no luck.

For example, I have the following code

```
<div data-width="123">  
 <p>Hi 123</p>
 <img src="123.jpg" />
</div>
```

and I need to transform every 123 to 999

```
<div data-width="999">  
 <p>Hi 999</p>
 <img src="999.jpg" />
</div>
```

I've tried using several "replacing" methods, but nothing works. I just need to replace with 999 where every 123.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you wrap using another element

```
<div class='test'>
    <div data-width="123">  
     <p>Hi 123</p>
     <img src="123.jpg" />
   </div>    
 </div>
```

You can do something like this

```
$('.test').html($('.test').html().replace(/123/g, '999'));
```

You basically take out all elements inside that element as string and do string replace and put the modified string back to the element.

See demo below

http://jsfiddle.net/petrabarus/Ph5Qz/

or you can just do this

```
$('body').html($('body').html().replace(/123/g, '999'));
```

Comment: You rock. Your last line saved my day. 

Such code, many thanks, so appreciate, very happy, wow.

Answer (score 2):

Try this... it might helps you.. Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Suxq8/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="target" data-width="123">  
 <p>Hi 123</p>
 <img src="123.jpg" alt="123.jpg" />
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var target = $(".target");
    var _replaced = target[0].outerHTML.replace(RegExp("123", "ig"), "999");
    $(_replaced).insertAfter(target);
    target.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div').each(function () {
if ($(this).data('width') == '123') {
    $(this).attr('data-width', '999');
    $(this).find('p').text('Hi 999')
    $(this).find('img').attr('src', '999.jpg')
}
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hk32N/5/)

Comment: This won't change the img src

Comment: Ummm, still I feel it's inefficient :)

Comment: thanks dude, but it does not replace data-width value :(